# Regex to match URL with specific file extentions, with or without scheme

Tags: regex

I need to match URL's which contain particular extentions (e.g. images).  There are many examples available on the web, but they don't suit my needs entirely.  The regex needs to match text where the scheme is included - e.g. `http://img.izismile.com/img/img7/20140124/640/morning_picdump_490_640_07.jpg` and also where the scheme is not included - e.g. `www.google.co.uk/images/srpr/logo11w.png`

The Regex I have come up with so far is

```
((?:(?:(?:http|ftp|gopher)\72\/\/)|(?:www|ftp)\.)S+\.(?:png|jpg))
```

But this doesn't appear to work - despite it looking correct in [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/)

Can somebody help me correct my regex please.

Comment: You are missing a backslash on your `S+` :)

Comment: Well that was an easy fix :)  Do you want to make that an answer, so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a backslash on your `S+` :)

```
((?:(?:(?:http|ftp|gopher)\72\/\/)|(?:www|ftp)\.)\S+\.(?:png|jpg))
```